# Select Menu discord.js v12

Tags: discord.js, dropdown

I wanted to ask if its possible to do a Select Menu (DropDown) in Discord.JS v12
I would be really happy is someone knows a solution.

Maybe there is any extra installtion requiered from some other source do let it work.

Comment: Don't use v12. It's only right way

Answer (score 1):

v12 Doesnt even have interaction support iirc, so no, it is not possible, and will never be possible. You should already have updated to a more recent version of the library.